# Question regarding charge and acceleration

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, waves, classical-electrodynamics

From a stationary charge electrostatic fields arise.
From a moving charge, magnetostatic fields arise.
From an accelerating charge, EM waves arise.

So i wonder -- what about a non-constantly accelerating charge? Is there meaning behind a 'jerking' charge i.e. for $\frac{d^3}{dt^3} \neq 0$? Or does the pattern listed above end at EM waves -- that he charge is accelerating produces EM waves regardless if that acceleration is constant or not.

Qaulitative or rigorous answers are fine. I'm just studying for an electrodynamics exam and found myself thinking about this.

Comment: hi i am open to correction on this, but acceleration (in whatever form you like) equates to em emission, afaik. regards

Comment: There's no doubt that non-uniformly accelerated charge radiates but the question of whether a uniformly accelerated charge radiates is subtle.  See, e.g., [Does A Uniformly Accelerated Charge Radiate?](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath528/kmath528.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It should be seen more like:

1. A stationary charge generates an electromagnetic field
2. A moving charge generates an electromagnetic field
3. An accelerating charge generates an electromagnetic field

So the hierarchy/pattern you mentioned isn't really much of a hierarchy/pattern after all. But actually, you can show that only the second derivative enters the equations of motion,
[and that is done on this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Corresponding_values_of_electric_and_magnetic_fields) ($\beta$ is the velocity divided by the speed of light - this makes the math nice, because then $\beta$ is unitless. So $\dot{\beta}$ is an acceleration). Therefore the answer is provably *no*, a "jerk" does not generate a field qualitatively different from an acceleration.